# Exiting scrollback mode in byobu

Tags: command-line, screen, byobu

In byobu, I am able to enter scrollback mode with F7. However, I am not able to exit by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> as documented. Nothing happens when I press <kbd>ESC</kbd>. In contrast, when I am in `screen`, I am able to enter scroll back and exit by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>. (Oddly, I also can't access scrollback by hitting alt-pgup. Maybe a terminal emulator issue?)

Comment: The reason why I fell into that mode was because I wanted to create a directory under `ranger` with the function key, moreover it everytime creates a new window when I want to save my file in `vim` because I map `F2` to save the file in vim. Byobu is somewhat "annoying" in that regard it precedes over all other applications for function keys. I don't want to remove `byobu`, it has an excellent name and a very colorful status bar, but I think at least it shouldn't take over all function keys which have uses elsewhere esp. in the context of most popular applications.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was able to exit scrollback by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Getting flashbacks of exiting vim... why dont simply keep F7 as on and off switch...

Answer (score 10):

Pressing <kbd>q</kbd> aborts the mode as well.

Discovered it via [tmux man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tmux.1.html), but it also works for session backed by `screen`.

Comment: works for `tmux` to (reported, confirmed)